# iOS Swift - Detect Items present on screen using UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout

Tags: uicollectionview, uiscrollview, delegates, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm trying to detect which item is on screen after a scroll action on my collection view, I've set the delegate to myself but the methods such as "scrollViewDidEndDecelerating" are not being fired on the scroll action.

I've used a custom collection view layout, using the new (iOS 13 introduced) UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout.

thainks in advance.